# Showing that the given expression is a polynomial so that one may use roots of unity filter for x^2022 coefficient finding?

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, generating-functions

> There is a polynomial $P(x)$ with integer coefficients such that $$P(x)=\frac{(x^{2310}-1)^6}{(x^{105}-1)(x^{70}-1)(x^{42}-1)(x^{30}-1)}$$ holds for every $0<x<1.$ Find the coefficient of $x^{2022}$ in $P(x)$.                 My approach was just the same as we do like expanding as infinite series for x<1 all the terms in the denominator . But i would like to know the reason **how the given expression is a polynomial** , how are we sure that the four denominator terms divides the   upper $(x^{2310} - 1)^6 $ for (0,1) and whats the degree of the polynomial ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x^a - 1 | x^{ab} - 1$

Or, $\frac {x^{ab} - 1}{x^a - 1} = 1 + x^a + x^{2a} + \cdots + x^{(b-1)a}$

Since $105, 70, 42, 30$ divide 2310, we know that p(x) will be a polynomial with integer coefficients.

$P(x) = (1 + x^{105} + x^{210} + \cdots + x^{2105})(1+x^{70} + x^{140} + \cdots + x^{2240})(1+x^{42}+\cdots + x^{2268})(1+x^{30} + \cdots + x^{2280})(x^{2310} -1)^2$

What is the coefficient of the $x^{2022}$ term?  It amounts to finding the number of solutions to $105a + 70b+42c+30d = 2022$ with $a,b,c,d$ being non-negative integers.